# Server hangs after typing reboot command

Tags: linux, debian, xen, kernel

I have a Debian Wheezy installation with Xen in kernel. All is fine but ... when I type a `reboot` command or `shutdown -r now`, my server is stuck and I see only that info on screen:

```
INFO: task reboot:15065 blocked for more than 120 seconds
```

I tried to change the kernel from wheezy to a kernel from backports - `3.10-0.bpo.2-amd64`, but it doesn't help.

Do you have some idea why and what is the problem?

Thank you for help.

Best,

Rafal

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking on the Debian Forums. Sounds like some kind of bug.

Comment: Maybe it is. But serverfault i think is good for that too.

Comment: What hardware do you have? I had a machine once that hung with messages similar to that...it was the RAID controller. One firmware update later and it's worked fine since.

Comment: Does anything get written to your logs that is relevant ?

Comment: I have Dell PowerEdge r720xd wirh Raid controler. Hmm maybe i have to upgrade firmware raid. I've checked logs and only that i have in dmesg.

Comment: Your server is a Dom0? Did all DomUs shut down before that reboot?

Answer (score 0):

The log you provided indicates an I/O problem.

You can start looking at and testing it with vendor provided tools.
It can be that this is not a hardware problem, but a Xen problem with
insufficient I/O performance.